# Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got undefined

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am getting this weird error while working on a Polymer component and that is not it the biggest problem is that chrome somehow crashes when I try to debug the Polymer library. I am at my wits end trying to solve this bug.

The premise is simple I have a component with property `data` which is an array and it's changed by another component by setting it like `someComponent.set('data', []);`. The set happens multiple times and the value set on `data` changes, at one point when the value is being set the error in title is thrown. Following is the stack trace, since I can't reproduce the bug in a jsbin.

`Polymer.dom                                             @   polymer-mini.html:1040
Polymer.Base._addFeature.serializeValueToAttribute      @   polymer.html:3416
Polymer.Base._addFeature.reflectPropertyToAttribute     @   polymer-micro.html:593
Polymer.Base.extend._reflectEffect                      @   polymer.html:1607
Polymer.Bind._modelApi._effectEffects                   @   polymer.html:1461
Polymer.Bind._modelApi._propertySetter                  @   polymer.html:1445
setter                                                  @   polymer.html:1524
Polymer.Base._addFeature.set                            @   polymer.html:2103
Polymer.updateTargets                                   @   t-demo-atom.html:234`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work:

-in the child, create a function to set data to an incoming value

-in the father, just call that function instead of setting the data value yourself